# Entity LINQ Enumerable Async

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have query where I need to sum all daily work. Problem is - I need it not to lock `UI` and be `async`, but `Enumerable` does not support `Async`. I use `Enumerable` to parse date `String` into `DateTime` object.

Any tips for same result but async.

```
var pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var result = (from w in db.Washes.AsEnumerable()
                group w by new {Date = DateTime.ParseExact(w.WashTime, pattern, null).Date}
                into g
                orderby g.Key.Date descending 
                select new DailyAverageModel {
                    Date = g.Key.Date,
                    NoOfWashesPerDate = g.Count()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: You should really be storing your date values as date values, rather than having your DB column be a string that you need to parse every time you want to use it in a query.

Comment: By using `AsEnumerable()` there be aware you are likely selecting all `Washes` from the database and applying the select and sort after. You are changing `db.Washes` from `Expression<Func<Washes,bool >>` to `Func<Washes, bool>`. This assumes db is your context

Comment: I didn't create DB and those tables. I see that Dates in DB are varchar. I can convert all dates that are varchar in Date type in SQL DB. I will rewrite all my queries to work with Date type? Then I have rewrite this code to the async one, others as well. Is that good aproach, I'm on time now. :)

Comment: What is the pattern for the datetime in the varchar field?

Comment: @Igor pattern is "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" --- Stock DateTime.Now.ToString();

Comment: `Stock DateTime.Now.ToString` <= no, that is only because your thread's culture happens to have it set that way. Run it on a different PC or with a user on the same PC with a different culture and you will get a different output. Again,  storing DateTime as a string is very bad practice. All data store providers that I know of support DateTime types.

Comment: I know that, thanks for the heads up, but I can always convert to this pattern when doing toString(). I will convert varchar to Date in DB and I can then use Async methods. That is best method, not so many entries there, I'm on time to redesign DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break it into 2 queries, 1 to retrieve which is async and one to create your result. That way the bottle neck, which is data store retrieval, can be run async which allows your UI to be responsive.

The substring of 10 characters is based on the format of your DateTime string which is formatted as `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"` (*see comments*).

```
var washes = await db.Washes
    .GroupBy(w => w.WashTime.Substring(0, 10))
    .Select(w => new {Date = w.Key, NoOfWashesPerDate = w.Count()})
    //.OrderByDescending(w => w.Date.Reverse()) // you could do this but the code would be more readable if this was omitted and done in memory
    .ToListAsync();

return washes.Select(w => new DailyAverageModel
{
    Date = DateTime.ParseExact(w.Date, pattern, null),
    NoOfWashesPerDate = w.NoOfWashesPerDate
}).OrderByDescending(w => w.Date).ToList();
```

*Note that sorting must be done in memory because sorting the string would yield an unexpected result (unless you reversed it and then sorted in the data store call).*

The real problem though is the data store schema stores `DateTime` values as a string. Always pick the appropriate type when designing your data stores. The type system exists for a good reason.

*note - [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/string-canonical-functions) is supported in EF.*

Comment: And now you're grouping everything in code instead of the database.

Comment: @DavidG - updated with a guess on how the date is stored in the string column.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - updated with a guess on how the date is stored in the string column.

Comment: Well guessing is even worse isn't it? What if the dates are `1st January 2018 12:00`?

Comment: The general idea and the comments make this answer good enough for the question. Not sure why so many downvotes

Comment: @DavidG - the OP clarified the pattern of the date time string.

Comment: This is good approach for this problem. It will be accepted, I will try it and in meantime I will redesign DB to proper type (Date).